# Por que no me llama la funcion del objeto y me lanza error

Tags: php

el problema es que  quiero usar el fecth_array por medio de la llamada del objeto y al llamarlo lo que muestra es un mensaje  asi:
* Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\Estudios WEB\Codigos Estudiados\Prinick\Prinick02\includes\class.Conexion.php on line 12*

```
   <?php

    class Acceso{
        protected $user;
        protected $pass;

        public function __construct($usuario,$password){
            $this->user = $usuario;
            $this->pass = $password;
        }

        public function Login(){
            $db = new Conexion();
            $sql = $db->query("SELECT nombre,password FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='$this->user' OR password='$this->pass'; ");
            $dato = $db->recorrer($sql);

            if(strtolower($dato['nombre']) == $this->user and strtolower($dato['password']) == $this->pass){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user'] = $this->user;
                header('location: acceso.php')

            }else{
                header('location: index.php?error=datos_incorrectos');
            }

        }

    ?>
```

**class conexion**

```
<?php
    class Conexion extends mysqli{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct('localhost','root','','prinick');
            $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
            $this->connect_errno ? die("Error de la Conexion"): $x = "SE Conecto";
            // echo $x;
            unset($x);
        }
    }

    public function recorrer($y){
        return mysqli_fetch_array($y);
    }
// $db = new Conexion();



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en que estas cerrando la clase y luego colocas el metodo, quizas el } se te esta olvidando que lo cerraste, intenta quitarlo:

```
<?php
class Conexion extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('localhost', 'root', '', 'prinick');
        $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $this->connect_errno ? die("Error de la Conexion") : $x="SE Conecto";
        // echo $x;
        unset($x);
    }


    public function recorrer($y)
    {
        return mysqli_fetch_array($y);
    }

}
?>
```

Aunque creo que mas bien deberia ser `return $y->fetch_array();` en el metodo recorrer.

Comment: no amigo ese no era el problema, el problema era que tenia que estar dentro de la class , eso era todo